# Compare a string and a list of strings for a certain occurance

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string, `"spaghet in insert in impossible(banana)"`(example string.), which I will call `testString`. I also have a list of each "word" in the string, generated using this code:

```
stringList = re.split("(\W)", testString)
for item in stringList:
    if item == "":
        stringList.remove(item)
```

The list looks like this:
`["spaghet", "in", "insert", "in", "impossible", "(", "banana", ")"]`
I need a function that gives me the start and end position of every occurrence of the word "in" in my **string** BY ITSELF. Essentially, it would match the "in" after "spaghet" and the "in" **after** "insert", but NOT the "in" **in** "insert".
In my current example, it would return `((9, 10), (19, 20))`. Of course, "in" is just a placeholder here, as it would be replaced with a meaningful string in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner-

```py
>>> import re
>>> [(m.start(0) + 1, m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'\bin\b', 'spaghet in insert in impossible(banana)')]
[(9, 10), (19, 20)]
```

### Explanation

We will use the regex `\bin\b` to match `in` words, feel free to change this to your liking.

`re.finditer` returns an iterable of [match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), match objects have the convenient [`start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) and [`end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.end) methods for extracting the start and end indices of each match (0-indexed).

You asked for the start index to be 1 indexed, so `m.start(0) + 1`, 0 being the full match (no captured groups)

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to substitute in for a variable in the regex?

Comment: @Blue a regex string is just a string, you can build dynamic strings using [fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). - `fr'\b{variable}\b'`. The second argument ofcourse is the actual string to test on, which you can pass a variable to, just like in any other function

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help.